# PKCS#11 C_WrapKey returns CKR_GENERAL_ERROR

Tags: c#, token, pkcs#11

I have followed the example: https://pkcs11interop.net/doc/_high_level_a_p_i_2_24__wrap_and_unwrap_key_test_8cs-example.html

to wrap symmetric keys using rsa keys and it worked.

What I am trying to achieve is to wrap an asymmetric key (rsa private key) instead. All I did was replacing the "secretKey" variable with an ObjectHandle of the private key. However, I get CKR_GENERAL_ERROR each time I call Wrapkey function.

Can someone explain why this won't work? I couldn't find anything in the specifications that prevents wrapping asymmetric keys.

The private key was generated with the following attributes:

```
List<ObjectAttribute> privateKeyAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true));
privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_PRIVATE, true));
privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_ID, ConvertUtils.HexStringToBytes(id)));
privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_SENSITIVE, false));
privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_DECRYPT, true));
privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_SIGN, true));
privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_SIGN_RECOVER, true));
privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_EXTRACTABLE, true));
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to wrap RSA private key using `CKM_RSA_PKCS` mechanim. Chapter 12.1.6 of [PKCS#11 v2.20 specification](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/blob/master/v2.20/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf?raw=true) states:

> The PKCS#1 v1.5 RSA mechanism, denoted `CKM_RSA_PKCS`, is a
>   multi-purpose mechanism based on the RSA public-key cryptosystem and
>   the block formats initially defined in PKCS#1 v1.5.
>
> ...
>
> This mechanism can wrap and unwrap any secret key of appropriate
>   length. Of course, a particular token may not be able to wrap/unwrap
>   every appropriate-length **secret key** that it supports. For wrapping, 
>   the "input" to the encryption operation is the value of the `CKA_VALUE` 
>   attribute of the key that is wrapped; similarly for unwrapping.

PKCS#11 specification uses term **secret key** only for symmetric keys. Moreover `CKA_VALUE` attribute is invalid for RSA private keys. This will not work.

Your best bet is to consolt the documentation of your device/library and choose different wrapping mechanism that suits your needs.